# Botones alineados segun columna bootrap

Tags: bootstrap

espero me puedan ayudar.
Actualmente cargo unos botones dinamicamente en mi pagina.
El primer row de 4 botones, el siguiente de 3 y asi sucesivamente (solo pongo el codigo de las 2 primeras filas).

```
                       <?php for($i= 1; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
                        {
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3'>";
                        if (${"estado".$i}=='Libre') {
                                 echo "<button class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-success' onclick=mostrar(${'identrenamiento'.$i})>";
                        }
                        else{
                             echo "<button href='' class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-danger'onclick=eliminar(${'idreservaentre'.$i})>";
                        }
                              echo "<i class='fas fa-dumbbell fa-4x'></i><br/>
                            ".${"estado".$i}." <br> ".${"entrenamiento".$i} ."
                        </button>
                    </div>";    
                            };
                        for($i= 5; $i <= 7 ; $i++)
                        {
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>";
                        if (${"estado".$i}=='Libre') {
                                 echo "<button class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-success' onclick=mostrar(${'identrenamiento'.$i})>";
                        }
                        else{
                             echo "<button href='' class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-danger'onclick=eliminar(${'idreservaentre'.$i})>";
                        }
                              echo "<i class='fas fa-dumbbell fa-4x'></i><br/>
                            ".${"estado".$i}." <br> ".${"entrenamiento".$i} ."
                        </button>
                    </div>";    
                            };?>
```

Se visualiza asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera que la segunda fila y cuarta fila se vean asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que deberia hacer para manejar las columnas de esa manera?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que faltaría es centrar el texto.

para esto bootstrap tiene una opcion que puedes añadir a las clases de los div: text-center

```
                   <?php for($i= 1; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
                    {
                    echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center'>";
                    if (${"estado".$i}=='Libre') {
                             echo "<button class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-success' onclick=mostrar(${'identrenamiento'.$i})>";
                    }
                    else{
                         echo "<button href='' class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-danger'onclick=eliminar(${'idreservaentre'.$i})>";
                    }
                          echo "<i class='fas fa-dumbbell fa-4x'></i><br/>
                        ".${"estado".$i}." <br> ".${"entrenamiento".$i} ."
                    </button>
                </div>";    
                        };
                    for($i= 5; $i <= 7 ; $i++)
                    {
                    echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center'>";
                    if (${"estado".$i}=='Libre') {
                             echo "<button class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-success' onclick=mostrar(${'identrenamiento'.$i})>";
                    }
                    else{
                         echo "<button href='' class='btn btn-sq-lg btn-space btn-danger'onclick=eliminar(${'idreservaentre'.$i})>";
                    }
                          echo "<i class='fas fa-dumbbell fa-4x'></i><br/>
                        ".${"estado".$i}." <br> ".${"entrenamiento".$i} ."
                    </button>
                </div>";    
                        };?>
```

Comment: Hola, lo puse pero no quedan como necesito, los de la segunda fila no quedan debajo de los espacios en blanco de los de arriba.